# JQuery on submit/onLoad not triggering fadeIn effect

Tags: jquery, submit, fadein

I have some data stored in a database and when the user types in their postcode a list of stores near them shows up in a list. I have called this in using PHP like this:

```
<div class="stores">
   <h3><?= $store['name'] ?></h3>
   <?= $store['address'] ?><br>
   <?= $store['city'] ?><br>
   <?= $store['county'] ?><br>
   <?= $store['postcode'] ?><br>
</div>
```

This displays the nearest 5 stores in a list.

The problem i have am having is when clicking on the submit button on the form nothings happening jQuery fadeIn wise- even tried an onlcick and onload alert('test'); this works but not firing the fadeIn. I have tried styling the boxes through css so when the user see the results each store fades in one after another and this was successful using this link: http://graphicfusiondesign.com/blog/design/creating-fancy-css3-fade-in-animations-on-page-load/

I am trying to do the same with jQuery and unsure of why this is not triggering as using the same class inside my jQuery as the css fadeIn.

jQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       $("#submit").click(function(){
       $(".stores:nth-of-type(3)").fadeIn(1000);
       $(".stores:nth-of-type(4)").fadeIn(2000);
       $(".stores:nth-of-type(5)").fadeIn(3000);
    });
  });
```

My form:

```
<input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?= $_GET['postcode'] ?>">                        
<input type="submit" value="search" id="submit">
```

Anyone have any suggestions or had this problem before?

Comment: on submit a form, your page is reloaded

Answer (score 0):

To see the effect:

```
$( document ).ready(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#submit").click(function(){
       $(".stores:nth-of-type(3)").fadeIn(1000);
       $(".stores:nth-of-type(4)").fadeIn(2000);
       $(".stores:nth-of-type(5)").fadeIn(3000);
    });
  });
```

But then, your form is not submited. You need to add some ajax logic then.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to fade in the elements before submitting the form try the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

       $("#submit").click(function(e){


e.preventDefault();
       $(".stores:nth-of-type(3)").fadeIn(1000);
       $(".stores:nth-of-type(4)").fadeIn(2000);
       $(".stores:nth-of-type(5)").fadeIn(3000,function(){
document.formname.submit();
});
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

    var form = $('#submit').closest('form'); // replace this with ID of the form

    form.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var self = this;
        $(".stores:nth-of-type(3)").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".stores:nth-of-type(4)").fadeIn(2000);
        $(".stores:nth-of-type(5)").fadeIn(3000, function() {
            self.submit();
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks guy's i will give these examples a go and let you's know.